# Issues in query on recyclerView from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Currently i'am facing with the issue is what while querying firebase recyclerView adapter for sorting dates ,everything works fine in that page, but when clicks on the particular event and goes to the next page some data's is missing or malfunctioning, look at the code below,

```
EventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String eventId = ds.child("Eid").getValue(String.class);
                    String serveCount = ds.child("Serve").getValue(String.class);

                    list.add(eventId);
                    list3.add(serveCount);

                }

                if (list.size() != 0)
                {
                   RecyclerView();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private void RecyclerView()
{
    Query ref = EventsRef.orderByChild("Sort_Date");

    //Display events
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WorkerMyEvents> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WorkerMyEvents>()
                    .setQuery(ref, WorkerMyEvents.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WorkerMyEventViewHolder eventsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final WorkerMyEvents newEvents)
        {
            //Id with date and time key
            final String IDs = getRef(i).getKey();
            final String eventIDs = IDs.substring(0,18);

            final String serve = list3.get(i);

            NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        //Here will have some data's to display...
                       // I will retrieve Eid from New Events node
                        eventsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Eid", Eid);
                                intent.putExtra("sC", serve);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                        eventsViewHolder.opt_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                DeletingEvent(IDs, Eid, serve);
                            }
                        });

                        eventsViewHolder.cash_received.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //notify to the participants...
                        //random key
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYY");
                        Date date = new Date();
                        String tdyDate = formatter.format(date);

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmma");
                        String saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

                        String randomkey = tdyDate + saveCurrentTime;
                        //random key


                        String Notify = "The event you participated has been deleted by contractor";
                        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("message", eventIDs + " - " + Notify);
                        workerRef.child("Notifications").child(randomkey).updateChildren(map);
                        workerRef.child("Notifications").child("current_counts").child(randomkey).updateChildren(map);

                        //remove Live event event id's from database...
                        EventsRef.child(eventIDs).removeValue();
                        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WorkerMyEventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.worker_my_event_layout, parent, false);
            WorkerMyEventViewHolder holder = new WorkerMyEventViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

this is my code all works fine in current activity. But while doing this  [ Query ref = EventsRef.orderByChild("Sort_Date"); ] some data's or reference problem is coming in the next page .

NextActivity(); //code where iam facing issue

```
ref3Male.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                //This needs to come ,if that query is not applied in the previous activity this works fine. but while using that it is not working, its movingto else part.
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In the above code actually the dataSnapShot will exists if the query is not applied in previous activity, but while using that it going to else part, Please guide me where i'm doing mistake friends. Thanks in advance.

[image]

By using the above database structure i will get key by sorting dates and by using the key i will get details from the node which that database structure is below ,( i posted only one node structure but it will have many)

[image]

That second image reference is what iam using in next activity()..

And also now i have noticed and changed that date type from string to long type using timestamp , but still having that issue ...

And also i researched something and noticed that in activity 1 there will have list of items in recycler view , in that only 1st and 2nd event is only  having that issue and remaining is working perfectly , by when i clicks that event those details viewing in next page.

Now i noticed another thing was in the activity 1 ,for 1st two items the reference is not working (ref - is in the 1st image) and the remaining is working perfectly.

```
public class WorkerMyEvents
{
private String Eid;

public WorkerMyEvents() {
}

public WorkerMyEvents(//Here also) {
   //Constructors
}

//Getters and setters
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I have posted and mentioned bro ..and one slight change in 1st image was , i changed that date type from string to long using timestamp

Comment: Please also add the content `WorkerMyEvents` class.

Comment: I don't know why you were asking this bro ..but i added that . because im getting only key values and using that key iam getting reference from another node and getting details.

Comment: The class is incomplete. Please add at least the variables.

Comment: I added bro . But I don't know why you were asking that.

Comment: Check the duplicate. See now why I was asking to post the content of the class?

Comment: Which duplicate , i couldn't understand and also i changed the Eid to eid in my model class and even in database .. but still not working properly

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you are passing the correct `EventID`, do this after click:**

```
eventsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity.class);

//pass the event ID
intent.putExtra("Eid", newEvents.getEid());

//pass other stuff if needed.......

startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

**In `onCreate()` method of `WorkerMyEventDetailsActivity`:**

```
//in onCreate()

String eventID = getIntent().getStringExtra("Eid");


//when you want to read the ref

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("New Events");


//read data

ref.child(eventID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
            //this should trigger and then you can get details.......
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: No bro .. Eid is correct , because iam displaying that eid in next activity in textview . Its displaying there . In the node newEvents its not giving reference to that id ,which i marked in second image, thats what i dont know .why it is ...but it showing problem for only 1st two items .. remaining working perfectly